# Регулярные выражения. Notepad++ Поиск блока содержащего два слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Всем привет.
Есть произвольный текст.

```
1 fgj sel dfjkd prm jfkdl frm jkl tbl klk
2 ledk prm jkl jkk frm jkl tbl jkl fjj
3 jklj sel prm kljlk jkjkl jkkl tbl emel
4 rui jkljl sel jklj jklj prm jkjl
5 jljkj frm jkljl jlj tbl mjljlk
```

Нужно регуляркой взять блоки которые начинаются с sel и заканчиваются tbl и при этом внутри себя содержат prm и frm. Т.е. блок состоит из последовательности слов sel prm frm tbl. 
В итоге из примера должны взяться часть первой строки и часть четвертой и пятой строки

```
sel dfjkd prm jfkdl frm jkl tbl

sel jklj jklj prm jkjl
5 jljkj frm jkljl jlj tbl
```

Сам пытался, но никак не выходит.

```
(sel)*?(prm|frm)?*(tbl)
```

Comment: А пятая строка почему?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте такое выражение `\bsel\b.*\b(prm|frm)\b.*\btbl\b`, здесь `\b` — граница слова, `.*` — любое количество любых символов

Comment: пятая потому что на на четвертой начало блока на пятой конец блока, текст многострочный, на четвертой sel начало блока, а на пятой конец блока tbl

Comment: \bsel\b.*\b(prm|frm)\b.*\btbl\b работает не совсем корректно. Первая строчка верно захватывается. Третья не верно, т.к. в ней нет слова frm. часть четвертой и пятой строки не захватываются ((

Comment: Теперь всё понятно, смотрите ответ

Comment: Хотя всё равно получается не совсем то что вам надо, надо добавлять просмотр вперед, видимо. Но это уже не сегодня. Может кто раньше меня напишет

Comment: Да немного не совсем то что надо, но близко. В любом случае спасибо,т.к. с регулярками я пока не очень дружу. И буду надеятся, что все таки будет более точный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
\bsel\b.*?\bprm\b.*?\bfrm\b.*?\btbl\b
```

И поставьте галочку "и новые строки"

Здесь перечислены все 4 нужных вам слова, при этом каждое слово обрамлено специальными квантификаторами `\b`, которые обозначают границу слов и сами по себе имеют нулевую длину, т. е. выражение `\bsel\b` захватывает слово `sel`, но не будет захватывать `select` или `useless`.

Также слова разделены выражением `.*?`, здесь `.` — любой символ, `*` — любое количество, `?` — делает это выражение ленивым, таким образом это выражение захватывает любую последовательность символов, но при этом длина ее будет минимальной достаточной, если это выражение не сделать ленивым, то полная регулярка будет захватывать только один блок — от первого `sel` до последнего `tbl`.